# Rails Active Record - find record where the sum of two columns matches criteria

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Property model that has `rooms` and `suites` columns.

If I want to find all Properties that have `rooms > 5`, I can easily write:

`Property.where("rooms > 5")`

But I want to write a query that finds any Properties that have +5 `rooms and suites`, so it can be `6 rooms and 0 suites`, `0 rooms and 6 suites`, `3 rooms and 3 suites` or any combination. What matters is that `rooms + suites > 5`.

How would I write such a query?

Comment: What db do you intend to use? Postgres? Mysql / MariaDB? In Postgres you would use [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try?

```
Property.where("(rooms + suites) > 5")
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your answer.  This should work.

Comment: And you can use interpolation to get the number from a variable "(rooms + suites) > #{number}"

Comment: @Aldana you should use `where("(rooms + suites) > ?", number)` just using string interpolation exposes you to SQL injections

Comment: @j-dexx Right. Much better!